# How to flip Twitter Bootstrap's Tooltips

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap to implement tooltips.  Currently, the tooltips appear above the link.  I would like the tooltip to appear underneath the link.  How would I go about doing this?

I am triggering the tooltip and it clearly states "bottom" but it doesn't want to work for me...

```
<script>$('#home').tooltip('hide bottom')</script>
```

Comment: can you show some type of code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#tooltip').tooltip({
    placement : 'left',
    title : 'first tooltip'
});
```

Use this inside `<script>` tags, or in a separate JavaScript file.

Comment: this one seemed to work for me!  thank you very much, i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the latest Bootstrap you would use the placement of "bottom". You can do this via the options when you create the tooltip: `$("#tt").tooltip({placement: "bottom"});` or via the data attribute on the element: `<span data-placement="bottom" ...>tooltip!</span>` I believe.

You can find more information on the tooltip in the [Bootstrap tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) section.

Answer (score 3):

on the bootstrap website they show options for the tooltips. one of the options is `placement`
which can be set to top, bottom, right or left.

so when you add the script for your tooltip put the option like this

```
$('#example').tooltip({placement: "bottom"})
```

Comment: So I modified the code based on your input, but the tooltips are still appearing above the links.  This is what I currently have:

    <script>$('#home').tooltip('{trigger:hover}{placement:bottom]')</script>

Comment: you need `"` around bottom and `}` at the end of bottom not `]`. everything else looks good

Comment: actually let me re-write that for you `<script>$('#home').tooltip('{trigger: "hover", placement: 
"bottom"}');</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap tooltip has a "placement" option. You can set it to "bottom" like this:

```js
$('#home').tooltip({
    placement : "bottom"
});
```

See their official website for references ([v.2.3.3](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips)) or ([v.3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)).

Comment: I dont think you need quotes around placement

Comment: Right. You don't have to if it's a valid variable name (in this case).

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore (assuming that the site is not just down)