# Position of Tooltip Bootstrap on Link with Icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and Font-Awesome for icon and I'm trying to add tooltips to them on link, but The tooltip can't get positioning correct on link with icon.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJBcp/7/)

```
#html

<div class="icon-head">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" data-original-title="Tooltip on top" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip" title=""><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

#css

.icon-head {
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.icon-head i {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.icon-head ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-left: 7%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.icon-head a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #34495e;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.icon-head a:hover {
    color: black;
}
.icon-head li {
    background: none;
    background-size: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
.icon-head li:hover {
    color: black;
    background: none;
    background-size: 0px;
}
```

I want tooltip display on center-top of icon.

Ok, I can fix with add `margin` on style of `tooltip` such as :

```
.tooltip.top {
    margin-top:-11px;
    margin-left:7px;
}
```

But, it can break a position other tooltip.

How can I fix them without add `margin` on style of `tooltip` ?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11568129/1388017 ?

Comment: After seeing `</br>` in your code, i closed you jsFiddle example page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

Remove `margin-left` on `.icon-head i` and add  `margin-left: 12%;` to `.icon-head ul`

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display:block;` and some padding to your link will make the tooltip behave better and be more consistent.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJBcp/8/)

Comment: I want tooltip display on center-top of icon. Your solution doesn't works for me.

Comment: your margin-left: 15px; is throwing it off, try removing that